# Which IPhone barcode reader

Tags: iphone, barcode, barcode-scanner

There are many barcode readers available for IPhone development. I intend to write an app that uses a barcode reader.

[VSBarcodeReader](http://www.visionsmarts.com/products/VSBarcodeReader/VSBarcodeReader.html)

Commerical license. Support all iPhones

[Pic2shop](http://www.pic2shop.com/developers.html)

Free license.  Support all iPhones

[ZBar](http://zbar.sourceforge.net/iphone/sdkdoc/faq.html)

Free license.  Supports 3GS & 4G

[zxing](http://code.google.com/p/zxing/source/browse/#svn/trunk/iphone)

Free license.  Support all iPhones

[ShopSavvy](http://shopsavvy.mobi/2010/12/29/shopsavvy-barcode-scanner-sdk-update-2/)

Commerical & ad supported license.

[Red Laser](https://www.redlaser.com/sdk/index.php)

Commerical license.  Supports 3, 3GS & 4G

Has anyone experimented with several of the above readers? Is one more reliable than another? Easier to use? Are the commercial ones more stable? Which one would you recommend or avoid?

Please only answer if you have used several different barcode readers.

Comment: Hi Andy, thanks for mentioning pic2shop and VSBarcodeReader.  Actually, both support all iOS devices with camera, even without autofocus (3G, iPod Touch 4, iPad2).  As far as I know, zxing is 3GS/4 only (autofocus) like Zbar.

Comment: i've edited the above table. Both the pic2shop, VSBarcodeReader and Zxing websites claim they support all iPhones.

Comment: Thanks!  The zxing home page mentions QR only.  The wiki mentions all iPhone 4.1 or above.  I am pretty sure it does 1D formats on iOS, and it may run on all devices, but to the best of my knowledge, it can only read UPCs and EANs on autofocus phones (unless the barcode is larger than average).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have used ZBar and Zxing.. the Best is Zbar!

Comment: Agreed. It's got a LOT better since the early days.

Comment: It won't support either iPad 2 and iPod Touch :/

Comment: it support iPod Touch 4G ... I tested this library on iPod touch and its working really great!

Comment: @Saurabh realy zbar works with ipod touch???/

Comment: @Aadil - yes we checked zbar on iPod touch 4G and its working great!

Comment: I can't seem to get ZBar to work with iPhone 3G and iPod (4th gen).  I don't believe they are supported because they have fixed-focus cameras, right?

Comment: they are supported .. I checked 3GS and iPod touch and they worked great with ZBar

Comment: This is INCORRECT. ZBar only works on devices with an auto-focus camera. Please stop spreading lies.